# Memory leak in Jupyter-Notebook with Anaconda 5.1.0 or newer when using matplotlib

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I was using Jupyter-notebook with the latest Anaconda (2018.12) and I noticed that it was using a huge amount of memory (around 6GB) for plotting and directly saving ~2000 figures (1920x1080) into .png files in Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried to reproduce that problem in my Mac with Anaconda 4.4.0, and the problem didn't occurred.

Later I tried to install several different versions of Anaconda into my Ubuntu machine and successfully reproduce the memory leak problem with simpler code.

It turned out that Anaconda 5.0.0 is the last version that doesn't have this particular memory leak problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
n = 0
dt = 0.01
w = 1

while n <= 1000:
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x + w*n*dt)
    plt.clf()
    plt.title("T = %.02f s." %(n*dt))
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig("dat/dat_%05d.png" % (n))
    plt.close()
    n = n+1
```

I am using htop to monitor the memory usage.

In Anaconda 5.0.0, it shows a constant 1.3% of memory usage in my machine with 8GB RAM.

In Anaconda 5.1.0, the memory usage starts at around 2% and rapidly increasing as it saves graphs into .png files, and reaches 16% of memory usage, and stays the same even after the cell's execution is finished.

I tried to use

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

and the memory usage is decreased a bit up to 12%.

And of course, by memory usage, I mean a memory usage only by those particular python process, not the whole system's memory usage.

Anyone already successfully resolve this memory leak problem in jupyter-notebook included in the latest Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the `y` variable every cycle of `while` is bad form, because the original object is still in memory somewhere, it just doesn't have a reference to it anymore.  You can use `del y` at the end of each while loop, before the `n = n+1` statement, but that ALSO does not release it from memory... it just sits around until Python's garbage collection gets to it.  Possibly adding that line might release the memory a little faster.

I'm assuming you've seen this:  https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Python-release-the-memory-when-I-delete-a-large-object

It might be faster for you to do the plot creation in smaller chunks, because of the garbage collection issue.